# Spring Security. Do smth before logout

Tags: spring-security

I want to update user's login history in database before spring delete authentication information. Would you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do it in two different ways:

- implement a custom [LogoutHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutHandler.html)
- implement a [LogoutSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.html) it is called after successfull logout BUT it contains the old authentication (prinicpal)

Comment: Note: You can set the LogoutSuccessHandler using namespace configuration, but you cannot set the LogoutHandlers that way.